# How can we load shared libraries (.so) from a jar file in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, java-native-interface

How can I load shared libraries from a jar file in gradle?

If I have a folder with the shared library it is straightforward:

```
System.loadLibrary("libname");
```

and I would specify the lib directory like:

```
systemProperty "java.library.path", file("${buildDir}/libs/native/").absolutePath
```

But how can this be done if the files are packed into a jar?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question but this doesn’t sound like a Gradle issue: if you want to package your native library with the Java classes in a JAR, then – with or without Gradle – you’ll need code that extracts the library before it can be used. Such a setup is comparably easy to achieve with JNA, if that’d be an option for you.

Comment: There are two things here: if you know where your file is, you can use `System.load(fileName)` instead of `System.loadLibrary(libName.so)`. If this case, you can put any file name you like as long as it represents library. If you want to load library from JAR, you have to do as @Chriki said: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo031